# Spark Dataset when to use Except vs Left Anti Join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, anti-join

I was wondering if there are performance difference between calling except (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#except(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) and using a left anti-join. So far, the only difference I can see is that with the left anti-join, the 2 datasets can have different columns.

Comment: Any value in the answer BTW?

Comment: May be accept the answer now?

Comment: No, since my question was not answered. I added a clarifying comment

Comment: 6 upvotes. Will look at though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your title vs. explanation differ, actually.

**Feb '24:** Your comment is noted and clarifies: *Let's say I have 2 datasets with the same schema, Dataset A and Dataset B. My goal is to find all the rows in Dataset A that are not present in Dataset B; should I do that with an EXCEPT or a LEFT ANTI JOIN?*

If you have the same structure in Datasets A & B, you would simply use EXCEPT. Using LEFT ANTI JOIN would be convoluted coding (as aluded to in Comments), but is technically possible.

> EXCEPT

is a specific implementation that enforces same structure and is a subtract operation, whereas

> LEFT ANTI JOIN

allows different structures to be compared and `where` clause is needed..

Use cases differ: 1) Left Anti Join can apply to many situations pertaining to missing data - customers with no orders (yet), orphans in a database. 2) Except is for subtracting things, e.g. Machine Learning splitting data into test- and training sets, or your use case "...new DataFrame containing only rows present in the DS A but not present in DS B ..."

Performance should not be a real deal breaker as they are different use cases in general and therefore difficult to compare. Except will involve the same data source whereas LAJ will involve different data sources.

**So, you need to use EXCEPT.**

Comment: I still don't have the answer to my question. Let's say I have 2 datasets with the same schema, Dataset A and Dataset B. My goal is to find all the rows in Dataset A that are not present in Dataset B; should I do that with an EXCEPT or a LEFT ANTI JOIN?

Comment: @alexgbelov If Dataset A and Dataset B have the same schema, using `EXCEPT` and `LEFT ANTI JOIN` are equivalent (assuming you join on all the columns in your `LEFT ANTI JOIN`.

If your schemas do not match, `EXCEPT` will return an error, so `LEFT ANTI JOIN` is more applicable.